# MS Access 2007 Recursive Find Summ Parents,Child and grandChild

Tags: sql, ms-access

У меня есть таблица в которой необходимо посчитать сумму часов у родительских нодов. Таблица одна. предполагаю, что если использовать sql, то в access потребуется несколько запросов. Надо найти суммы всех родительских нодов их детей и внуков. Главный родительский нод должен получить в результате запросов общую сумму. Остальные родительские запросы сумму часов себя и всех своих детей. Пример таблицы приложен на скрине. Прошу помощи. Мне удалось Суммировать только непосредственных родителей и детей, но не внуков. Как суммировать результат с нодами третьего уровня в Access.

*SELECT Child_id, Child_id as root_id FROM [tble]
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Child_id, s.Child_id FROM [tble] t INNER JOIN [tble] s ON ( s.Child_id = NZ(t.Parent_id,0) );* ---->  QRY

Далее второй запрос:

SELECT ttt.Parent_id, ttt.Child_id, Sum(ttt1.Hours_planned) AS [Sum-Hours_planned]
FROM ([QRY] AS s INNER JOIN [tble] AS ttt
ON s.root_id = ttt.Child_id) INNER JOIN [tble] AS ttt1 ON s.Child_id = ttt1.Child_id
GROUP BY ttt.Parent_id, ttt.Child_id
ORDER BY ttt.Parent_id;

в результате суммы только по родителям и детям, а надо чтобы суммы были и по корневому ноду. И чтобы часы внуков суммировались к родительским(второго уровня) нодам и нодам первого уровня (grandfather).

Помогите пожалуйста кто знает как это сделать в Access.

|     [image: введите сюда описание изображения]    |

Comment: Translate your question to Russian please

Comment: Перевел на русский